# how to pass the id of a div to another php page when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to pass the id of a particular div in a P.H.P page to another P.H.P page when it is clicked dynamically.The div who's id i want to pass, is created dynamically.So far I have fetched the id of the div dynamically by using Java script, but i cant seem to pass this value to another P.H.P  page.

```
<?php 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
      $link = $row["video_link"];
                            $video_id = explode("?v=", $link);
                            $video_id = $video_id[1];

?>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
 <div class="post_list_content_unit">
    <div class="post_list_featured_image"  onclick="markActiveLink(this);" id="<?php echo  $video_id?>">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function markActiveLink(e) {   
    alert(e.id);
}
</script>
<a href="video_tut.php" title="View post details">
    <img width="370" height="193" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo  $video_id?>/hqdefault.jpg" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="Teen girl sitting with a laptop" />

?>
```

Comment: May we see the codes?

Comment: i want to pass the id of the div class="post_list_featured_image" into another php page, when it is clicked dynamically when the page is loaded.

Comment: It's a clickable image?

Comment: yes. It is a clickable image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will suffice, but you could try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo 'video_tut.php?vid_id='.$video_id; ?>" title="View post details">
    <img width="370" height="193" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo  $video_id?>/hqdefault.jpg" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="Teen girl sitting with a laptop" />
</a>
```

Instead of getting the `id` from the `div`, I added the `id` as a GET query in the `href` of the `a` element. Then in the `video_tut.php`, you can use this to get the `id` value:

```
if(isset($_GET['vid_id'])){
    $vidID = $_GET['vid_id'];
}
```

Here I'm assuming that exposing the `$video_id` in the URL does not pose some sort of security risks.

Comment: no .. passing the id directly onto the href is not feasible for me, because the id i want to pass, will further be passed in a query in the second php page.

Comment: You could use the second code to get the `id` from the URL, then you can use it wherever you want

Comment: Try to use it now.

Comment: Where did you put the `if` condition? What does the URL looked like when you click the `a`?

Comment: i inserted the IF condition just after the script tag, and the URL after clicking the image is:http://localhost/march/21_march/vt/video_tut.php

Comment: No wonder it does not worked. Put the `if` in the `video_tut.php`, and it seems that you didn't use the first code, that's why the URL is still the same

Comment: thank you brother, it worked .Finally got this in the URL "http://localhost/march/21_march/vt/video_tut.php?vid_id=t0bTt-rMsSU"